# Excel is freezing when importing large CSV

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I have a very large CSV file, with 60 columns and 50k rows. (I can't show you because it is in the intranet.)

I wrote VBA code that does this:

```
Columns("D:BF").Select
Selection.ClearContents
*Code to import csv file to D1*
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
Range("A1:C1").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("A2:C" & lastrow).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

It was working, but has stopped working. When I run the macro Excel freezes. I need to press "Esc" and the macro stops, then the debugger says the PasteSpecial is wrong. 
But it is not, if I run a macro only to import, and press "Esc", it imports very well, then I run the second macro to paste the formulas until the last row and it runs very well too.

The workbook is in manual calculation

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKzJE.jpg

Comment: #felipe31 are you sure of your code?!?!? you select cells("D:BF") and you clear those, then the LastRow will be D1 !!!

Comment: @Fabrizio the OP is clearing the old data before he imports the new data.

Comment: @ThomasInzina is right

Comment: With Excel 2010 and above you can try importing with Power Query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the CSV file line by line into an array that is 10,000 rows by 100 columns.  When the array is full I write it into Excel, redim the array and continue until the end of file.

I originally tried to use a dynamic array but it Excel would freeze up.  Using the static array is actually more efficient.

You'll need to adjust the constant values.  From your image it looks like your file is semi-colon delimited.  It does matter if `ColumnCount` is exact as long as it is greater than or equal to the actual column count.

```
Const CSVFileName = "C:\Users\best buy\Downloads\stackoverfow\Sample Data File\R58K x C60.csv"
Const Delimiter = ","
Const PageSize = 10000
Const ColumnCount = 100
```

It takes about 32 seconds to import 100,000 rows and 64 columns.  The CSV file is 69.5 MB on disk.

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Sub ProcessFile()
    Const CSVFileName = "C:\Users\best buy\Downloads\stackoverfow\Sample Data File\R58K x C60.csv"
    Const Delimiter = ","

    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

    Debug.Print Now
    Dim Start: Start = Timer

    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim arFormulas
    arFormulas = Range("A1:C1").Formula

    Columns("A:BF").ClearContents

    ImportCSVFile CSVFileName, Delimiter

    Debug.Print "Time to import CSV file in seconds:"; Timer - Start
    Start = Timer

    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

    Range("A1:C" & lastRow).Formula = arFormulas

    Debug.Print "Time to add formulas in seconds:"; Timer - Start

    Debug.Print "Column Count:"; Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Columns.Count
    Debug.Print "Row Count:"; Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .AutoRecover.Enabled = True
    End With
End Sub

Sub ImportCSVFile(FilePath As String, Delimiter As String)
    Const PageSize = 10000
    Const ColumnCount = 100

    Dim line As String
    Dim arData, arLine
    Dim x As Long, y As Long, z As Long
    ReDim arData(PageSize, ColumnCount)
    z = 1

    Open FilePath For Input As #1                     ' Open file for input
    Do While Not EOF(1)                               ' Loop until end of file
        Line Input #1, line
        arLine = Split(line, Delimiter)

        y = 0
        For y = 0 To UBound(arLine)
            arData(x, y) = arLine(y)
        Next
        x = x + 1

        If x = PageSize Or EOF(1) Then

            Range("D" & z).Resize(x, y) = arData
            z = z + x
            ReDim arData(PageSize, ColumnCount)
            x = 0
        End If

    Loop

    Close #1

    Erase arData
End Sub
```

Comment: I'll try this tomorrow and I tell you

Comment: It doesnt work, the problem is on importing. I did a macro just to import and it keeps freezing and i need to press esc

Comment: If "the problem is on importing" then you should post this code:"*Code to import csv file to D1*"

Comment: Posted the link up there

Comment: You code is just a standard text file import.  I don't know why it stopped working.  I would have posted the code and change the file path to `C:\Users\Data Files\sample.xlsm`.  In an hour or so I will update my answer to read and import the csv file line by line.  It will be a little slow nut shouldn't freeze up.

Comment: Yea, I don't know either. The screen becomes white and shows Not Responding, and be there like for maaaany minutes, I never really went to the end. When I press "Esc" the data was imported but if the macro has more sentences, it will stop before the next sentence.

Comment: It worked! Its giving me 1 empty column between each column of data, you know why?

Comment: @felipe31 Sorry about that,  I reworked my code and had left an unneeded line in there `y = y +1`.  Remove that line.  I'm updating my answer now.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you. Could you explain how the Importcsvfile works?

Comment: `ReDim arData(PageSize, ColumnCount)` defines a 2 dimensional array with 10K rows and 100 columns.  `Importcsvfile` opens up the CSV (which is just a text file) and reads it line by line.  Each line is split, by the delimiter, into a 1 dimensional array (e.g. arLine).  The `For y` loop transfers the 1D array data into Row x of the 2D array, When the 2D array `arData` is filled or the end of the CSV file is the data is transferred to the WorkSheet and the variables are reset (arData is Redim to clear the data and x is reset to 0).

Comment: The trick is that variables `x` and `y` mark the last used row and column of the arData.  I use this values to resize the next empty cell's range to fit the actual used elements of arData.  The extra empty rows and columns are ignored.

Comment: Hello again! It's been working very well, thank you. But now I've got other issues. The csv file has some data in format: dd/mm/yyyy and Comma as decimal delimiter. So it imports 31800 instead of 31.8 and the day becomes month, month becomes day. Any solution?

Comment: @felipe31 You'll need to preprocess the line before splitting it.  Post a line of raw data in a comment and write a function to correct the issue.

Answer (score 0):

use `doevents`command after paste...I hope it works